# Stripping out results from a website that doesn't have differing URLs

Tags: ruby, regex, automation, watir, hpricot

I'm trying to automate the process of searching for alternative telephone numbers using [SayNoTo0870](http://www.saynoto0870.com) . Every time one searches for an alternate number or name it brings up the `'/companysearch.php'` page.

Clearly this page has no reference, and in my mind you can't just link to this page.

What I'm hoping to do is use the code below, to automate the opening of a browser, searching of a name/number, stripping out the HTML and then providing the top 5 results. I've got the automation part down, but clearly when trying to save the webpage using Hpricot it only brings up the 'Sorry nothing can be found page' because I can't link directly to the search result page.

Here is my code thus far: 
(I've removed comments to shorten it)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'



class OH870


    def searchName(name)
        browser = Watir::Browser.new
        browser.goto 'http://www.saynoto0870.com/search.php'
        browser.text_field(:name => 'search_name').set name
        browser.button(:name => 'submit').click
    end 

    def searchNumber(number)

        browser = Watir::Browser.new
        browser.goto 'http://www.saynoto0870.com/search.php'
        browser.text_field(:name => 'number').set number
        browser.button(:name => 'submit').click
    end 

    def loadNew(website)

        doc = Hpricot(open(website))
        puts(doc)   

    end


    def strip_tags
        stripped = website.gsub( %r{</?[^>]+?>}, '' )
        puts stripped
    end

end # class

class Main < OH870
puts "What is the name of the place you want?" 
website = 'http://www.saynoto0870.com/companysearch.php'

    question = gets.chomp
    whichNumber = OH870.new
    whichNumber.searchName(question)
    #result = OH870.new
    #withoutTags = website.strip_tags
    #result.loadNew(withoutTags)
end
```

Now I'm not sure whether there's a way of "asking watir to follow through to the companysearch.php page and dump the results without having to pass this page as a variable.

I wonder if anyone has any suggestions here?

Comment: First off, hpricot and open-uri are superfluous when using WATIR. WATIR already interacts with/accesses DOM elements.  Can you also write out your test case?  From my first read this sounds like a really straightforward application for WATIR but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Me neither. Not sure what Josh is doing.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't go as far as having a test case, having the code run is as far as I go to test it! 

The easiest way for you to understand is to go to the sayNoTo0870 site, try a name of a place that has a switchboard, say Hilton, and see what I'm seeing. 

I'm just trying to strip the content displayed after each search and have it displayed in the console/ terminal. 

To be perfectly honest with you, I'm a terrible programmer, I'm trying to learn by asking a LOT of questions!

Comment: Josh, your test case just tells you/us what you expect to see.  "When I got to X page and search for Y, I should see (something)".  You have one, but you probably think it can't be that simple ;).  I was having trouble grasping that "something" based on the original question, but I think I got it below.

Comment: Not sure what your purpose is in automating the searches, but I do hope you paid attention to this text at the bottom of the main page --Written permission is required to duplicate any of the content within this site.--

Comment: Just for the purpose of learning, nothing specific really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WATIR, minus the extraneous libraries, here's all it takes to accomplish what you've described (using the 'name' test case only).  I've pulled it out of the function format since you already know how to do that, and this will be a clearer test case path.

```
require 'watir'

@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox   #open a browser called @browser

@browser.goto "http://(your search page here)"         #go to the search page
@browser.text_field(:name => 'name').value = "Awesome" #fill in the 'name' field
@browser.button(:name => 'submit').click               #submit the form
```

If all goes well, we should now be looking at the search results.  WATIR already knows it's on a new page - we don't have to specify a URL.  In the case that the results are in a frame, we do need to access that frame before we can view its content.  Let's pretend they're in a DIV element with an ID of "search_results":

```
results = @browser.div(:id => "search_results").text

resultsFrame = @browser.frame(:index => 1)                #in the case of a frame
results = resultsFrame.div(id => "search_results).text
```

As you can see, you do not need to save the entire page to parse the results.  They could be in table cells, they could be in a different div per line, or a new frame.  All are easily accessible with WATIR to be stored in a variable, array, or immediately written to the console or log file.

```
@results = Array.new                #create an Array to store our results

@browser.divs.each do |div|         #for each div element on the page
   if div.id == "search_results"    #if the div ID equals "search_results"
      @results << div.text          #add it to our array named @results
   end
end
```

Now, if you just wanted the top 5 [there are many ways to access them](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html).

```
@results[0]      #first element
@results[0..4]   #first 5 elements
```

I'd also suggest you look into a few programming principles like DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  In your function definitions where you see that they share code, like opening the browser and visiting the same URL - you can consolidate those:

```
def search(how, what)
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  @browser.goto "(that search url again)"
  @browser.text_field(:name => how).value = what
  etc...
end

search("name", "Hilton")
search("number", "555555")
```

Since we know that the two available text_field names are "name" and "number", and those make good logical sense as a 'how', we can parameterize them and use a single function for both the Search by Name and Search by Number test cases.  This is more efficient, as long as the test cases remain similar enough to be shared.

Comment: Clearly I'm not as bad as explaining things as I first thought!

Comment: Josh, if this works for you, please click "Accept" next to this answer - thanks!

Comment: If you have to search the page for multiple divs with the same ID, there's something very wrong with the code on that site since per the HTML standards, ID values should be unique within a page.  Now if it was Name or Class, then yes, I could see having to use that method of finding the results rows.

Comment: Good point Chuck, but I would argue that most of the sample code I've seen here from people asking questions isn't up to W3C standards... so I was just giving them a familiar example!